Zod validation issue condition wise
The email validation will be shown by default. If a value is added to the contactNumber, the email will not be required. However, if we remove the value from the contact Number, the email will become required.
Make the email field optional when a value is added to the contact Number field; otherwise, keep it required.

Please add your codes to the question and provide information to reproduce the issue.

You could utilise the union type for this
const base = z.object({
  other: z.string(),
  fields: z.string(),
  email: z.string(),
  contactNumber: z.string().optional()
})

const emailOptional = base.extend({
  email: z.string().optional(),
  contactNumber: z.string()
})

const schema = z.union([base, emailOptional])

type Schema = z.infer<typeof schema>

const test: Schema = {
  other: '',
  fields: '',
} // Email is required by default

const test2: Schema = {
  other: '',
  fields: '',
  contactNumber: ''
} // Email is optional when providing a contactNumber



const contactFormSchema = toTypedSchema(
z.object({
email: z.string({ required_error: "Email  is required" }),
contactNumber: z.any({
  required_error: "Contact Number is required"
}),


const handleSubmit = useForm({
validationSchema: contactFormSchema,
initialValues: {}
});

this is my code
